# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable occurring only on big data

Tags: python, anaconda

I get the error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable 
when i try to geocode over 200K IPs  using the following code excerpt. Please note that when I geocode just 100K IPs no errors are occurring:

```
#writing a function that takes index, geocodes the ip individually for multithreading 
def new_geocode_ip_ver2(ipandresponse):
        if ipandresponse[1]!='0':
            match=geolite2.lookup(ipandresponse[0])
            if match is not None: 
                lat, lng = match.location 
            else:
                lat="GC failed"
                lng="GC failed"
        else:
            lat="Non-pingable, no GC"
            lng="Non-pingable, no GC"

        return lat, lng

#spawn threads for geocoding IPs
pool=ThreadPool(200)
latlng_result=pool.map(new_geocode_ip_ver2,ip_response)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

The error is message is provided below. Can anyone tell me why this error is occuring on over 100k IP only. I am trying to build my program in such a way that I will be able to geocode a million + IPs. Do I have some kind of memory leak by any chance?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-26e36f25645e> in <module>()
     32 #spawn threads for geocoding IPs
     33 pool=ThreadPool(200)
---> 34 latlng_result=pool.map(new_geocode_ip_ver2,ip_response)
     35 pool.close()
     36 pool.join()

C:\Users\sibag\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\pool.pyc in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    249         '''
    250         assert self._state == RUN
--> 251         return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
    252 
    253     def imap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=1):

C:\Users\sibag\Anaconda2\lib\multiprocessing\pool.pyc in get(self, timeout)
    565             return self._value
    566         else:
--> 567             raise self._value
    568 
    569     def _set(self, i, obj):

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Where are you getting `ip_response` from? Seems to me that at some point you're passing a `NoneType` object as `ip_response`.

Comment: I am getting it like this:                                                                            '#spawn multiple threads
pool=ThreadPool(200)
response=pool.map(ping,ips)
pool.close()
pool.join()
print("Finished pinging IPs")

<code>
aips=numpy.array(ips)
aresponse=numpy.array(response)
ip_response=numpy.column_stack((ips, response))' </code>

Comment: I get it like this: ip_response=numpy.column_stack((ips, response))

Comment: @RuslanSibagatullin did you worked around this issue? If so, what you did?